# URL containing closing parentheses are trunked in comments (javadoc idiom)

Tags: bug, status-completed

Hi, 
here is an example :

http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#expiration(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

see comment.

Comment: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#expiration(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: A travesty of a bug if I've ever seen one!

Comment: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#expiration%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29

Answer (score 4):

I doubt we'll get this fixed, but you can resolve it yourself by URL encoding `(` and `)` as `%28` and `%29`.  Since one of these bugs gets posted every two to three days, here's a simple rule of thumb:

> Any characters in your URL other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `/.=?-+%&*` (and the `:` in "`http:`") should probably be URL encoded.

I've cobbled together a quick page that will encode the things that shouldn't need encoding.  You can find it [here](http://bstorer.com/so/encode.html).  It doesn't use any jQuery, so it's probably completely unreliable.  If you find anything it should be encoding but isn't, let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I feel lazy doing myself what the machine can do for me.

Comment: The machine will do it for you at the link I've provided.  Jeff has said that neither the Javascript nor server-side renderer is maintained by the SO team, so it's probably your best bet.

Comment: Parentheses can't be escaped in anchor links, though. Try http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html#expiration%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29 and it won't get you to the exact method. (I think parentheses aren't allowed in anchors by the standard, which could explain this behavior.)

Comment: I should note that I've only tested this on IE7, though.

Comment: It works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Parens at the end are highly problematic because users looooove to enter URLs like this (http://www.example.com) but other than that, it should work now, as long as you encode any spaces.

Comment: OMG! The Jeff Atwood spoke to me ! I want a badge for that ! :)

Yes, I though that was the reason, I'm used to add a space before the closing parenthesis but I can hardly blame people who don't.
What about trying to balance the parenthesis in the url ? Or trying to ping the url with various interpretations until it stop giving a 404 ?

Comment: +1 @nraynaud for balancing parentheses.