# URL links not parsing correctly on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, hyperlinks

The following link doesn't parse correctly on StackOverflow website.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx

It breaks on the '(' character, it seems.

Comment: It seems that it breaks here too.

Comment: Well, geez, this is only the 500th time this has been brought up. Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like I just recently [discussed this very issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/url-containing-closing-parentheses-are-trunked-in-comments-javadoc-idiom/13714#13714):

> I doubt we'll get this fixed, but you
>   can resolve it yourself by URL
>   encoding `(` and `)` as `%28` and
>   `%29`.  Since one of these bugs gets
>   posted every two to three days, here's
>   a simple rule of thumb:
>
> > Any characters in your URL other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `/.=?-+%&*`
> >     (and the `:` in "`http:`") should
> >     probably be URL encoded.
>
> I've cobbled together a quick page
>   that will encode the things that
>   shouldn't need encoding.  You can find
>   it [here](http://bstorer.com/so/encode.html).  It doesn't use any
>   jQuery, so it's probably completely
>   unreliable.  If you find anything it
>   should be encoding but isn't, let me
>   know.

Comment: it is fixed now, we basically force-encode it for everyone

Comment: I'm not sure this is fixed:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762692/teamcity-users-a-few-questions/1297765#1297765
Looks fine in the edit preview, but not in the answer page (using firefox). Tried different formats, encoding the '#' character, with no luck.

Comment: @brass-kazoo: You are correct: it was encoding `#` when it should have left it alone.  But the actual problem in that answer is that you left the `http://` off of the link to andariel, which was screwing things up.  I've edited your answer to fix that.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: [this still fails on SO!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_(subroutine))

Comment: @eSKay we don't support that in comments, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/comments-inline-links-with-a-parenthesis-not-working-properly/49222#49222