# Comments inline links with a parenthesis not working properly

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

Is there a different syntax for commenting with links that contain parentheses?  I tried something like this:

```
[my text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(SQL.90).aspx)
```

And that yielded this in the comment:

> my text.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses

Comment: It's different in comments... [like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: [my text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439%28SQL.90%29.aspx) <-- escaped using %28 and %29

Comment: For Microsoft links, often you can just remove the part in parenthesis, and [the link will still work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx)

Comment: In fact, it's best to leave off the parenthesis part for MSDN links. That way, they'll always link to the latest version. Try it without the parens, first, to be sure.

Comment: @balpha isn't this a feature request more than a bug? Looks like you added new feature of supporting one level of parentheses rather then fixing a bug. No?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I'm not to hung up on the distinction between the two in this case, both have a point. Also note that this change was made ages ago; I just noticed this question (because an [old dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74123/some-urls-create-broken-links-in-comments) just floated to the top of meta).

Comment: @balpha OK fair enough. I was thinking to add this to the [feature change log](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) what do you think?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd The change [is from January 2011](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63399/revisions), so it's a stretch to call it recent -- but do as you please :)

Comment: @balpha being a complete log, I couldn't resist editing it with this. Easier to find when something was done. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same syntax, but rendering balanced matching parens is quite expensive in regex, and the comment regexes are run every time the post loads and displays -- so the support in comments isn't as good as in posts. We do however support one level of balanced parentheses, which covers your case.

As Jon noted, use `%28` and `%29` to encode the parens in cases where they aren't balanced or are nested more than one level deep.

Comment: I cannot get this to work with the following link: `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.CopyOption...)` According to what I've read, it should work (there is only one pair of parens).  I have tried to use `%28` and `%29`, but it's not working.  Is it possible to include a link when the URL _ends_ with a paren?