# Bug in comment markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

A parenthesized link:

```
([Foo](http://stackoverflow.com/))
```

works in an answer, but not in a comment.

Comment: ([test](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69313/bug-in-comment-markdown))

Comment: [(Another test)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69313/bug-in-comment-markdown)

Comment: Why do people use all these fancies ways to post links in a *comment*?

Comment: @Lady - you're just jealous.

Comment: ( [Foo](http://stackoverflow.com)) <-- The bug is with the first parenthese, not the second.

Comment: @Jon: Jealous of comments?

Comment: Oh, look, @Tom is cheating. :)

Comment: These pretty much always get closed as [status-bydesign]

Comment: Some examples: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/#comment-166893

Comment: Related question with answer by Jeff: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/comments-inline-links-with-a-parenthesis-not-working-properly

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead:

```
[(Foo)](http://stackoverflow.com)
```

(The parentheses will be part of the link, but I think that's close enough to what you were trying to do)

Comment: *sigh*...  I "solved" it in the same way that TomWij did -- by inserting a space after the open paren, which is even closer.  But still, I would consider any differences between the markdown in the two cases to be a bug.  (Yeah, some things are not sensible in a comment -- better to error or intentionally ignore them than to behave differently.)

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over this post. This was fixed  a long time ago, as the first comment under your question shows.