# Some URLs create broken links in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments inline links with a parenthesis not working properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/comments-inline-links-with-a-parenthesis-not-working-properly)

I tried to add the following URL to a comment on a post on Stack Overflow.

```
http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Web_Application_Fingerprint_(OWASP-IG-004)
```

When I typed in the URL, a link was auto-generated. However, the auto-generated link was broken (missing a parenthesis).

The original post is here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618012/telling-between-a-natural-http-404-and-a-php-generated-one/4618325#4618325
```

but I've since removed the comment with the broken link, and added the link to the main post body as a workaround.

Comment: Including the link here as an example (as to see if it's also broken on meta) http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Web_Application_Fingerprint_(OWASP-IG-004)

Comment: This was [recently announced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63366/would-it-be-possible-to-fix-links-containing-parentheses-in-comments) as something that will be fixed in the next build. The issue is because of the parentheses - comment markdown only checks for the next closing set, not to try and pair them. Until the fix is issued, you can still add them by encoding the parens as `%28` and `%29`. In itself, though, this question would be a duplicate of [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/comments-inline-links-with-a-parenthesis-not-working-properly).

Comment: @Grace Note: the fix is about `[link text](http://url)` style links, not the automatically recognized ones.

Comment: @balpha Oh, hey, nevermind. I just noticed that this was a plain URL rather than a Markdown one.