# Problem showing links with closing parenthesis as part of the link

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autogenerated links truncate a final closing bracket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127290/autogenerated-links-truncate-a-final-closing-bracket)

Clicking on the following will go to the wrong location in the page (some escaped and some not):
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory(java.lang.String) - Escaped
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory(java.lang.String) - Not escaped

Comment: Using proper markdown might be an answer to this.

Comment: To me, both the links take to `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory(java.lang.String`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno and it's the wrong one - without the closing right parenthesis.

Comment: @TimStone you are right, but it's not related to auto-generated links.  I didn't find it when I searched for similar posts.

Comment: Anyhow, it seems a bug. How do we escalate it to a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. In your question as it currently stands, both links go the the same URL (your escape failed).

However, in the editing view the the first link as shown in the preview is properly escaped.

So, the issue here seems to be "**why is the preview parsing links differently from the actual post?**". More specifically, using a backslash to escape the trailing parenthesis works in the preview (!) but not in the actual post.

---

That aside, you can avoid having to manually escape the chars if use the appropriate markdown for linking. See [Would it be possible to fix links containing parentheses in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63366/would-it-be-possible-to-fix-links-containing-parentheses-in-comments)

Also note the [Bare URLs section in the editing help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls) which states that you should enclose the bare URLs with angle brackets if they contain *unusual chars*, or use the [proper markdown syntax for linking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#basic-links).

Example: Raw link enclosed in angle brackets - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addCategory(java.lang.String)

Comment: To answer your bolded question, see [this comment of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127290/autogenerated-links-truncate-a-final-closing-bracket#comment345931_127295).

Comment: @TimStone ah... thanks. Was looking for a post on that and was close to posting a Q of my own.

Comment: This is correct, so how can we escalate it to a bug?

Comment: @kilaka You've already done so (posting on MSO and tagging it with [bug]). However, do note that what you've posted has already been discussed several times in the past (see links in other comments).