# Links to Java documentation broken

Tags: bug, link-validator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autogenerated links truncate a final closing bracket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127290/autogenerated-links-truncate-a-final-closing-bracket)

Let's say there's a question about how to get a character from a String at a certain index (just an example). I say, "Oh, I'll just link to the Javadocs!" So I go merrily along to the Javadocs and I find the page for the `String` class, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). I scroll down to the `charAt` method:

[image: Clicking on "charAt" method (with a freehand red circle :D)]

So I copy and paste it and don't realize the inevitable doom of the link not jumping down to the specified method because of this:

[image: Oh noes, parenthesis at the end (more RFHC)]

Which Stack Overflow treats like this:

[image: Ahhh! Bad link!]

Simple fix: just don't omit the close parenthesis from the link if the link contains an open parenthesis after the last slash.

Comment: Workaround: [do this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)): `[do this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))`