# URL not handled correctly in Comments

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

I was answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333028/how-to-access-a-control-from-a-contextmenu-menuitem-via-the-visual-tree/11339065#comment14966265_11339065) question and was trying to post following url in comments but everytime it failed -

[http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-*3D00*-BAML-not-IL.aspx](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-_3D00_-BAML-not-IL.aspx)

I searched on Meta and came across [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13768/url-links-not-parsing-correctly-on-stackoverflow) post and tried the solution posted but url is already encoded and doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this work in comments?

Comment: What we need here is a [status-official-feature]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Yes*, we probably shouldn't be applying `_blah_` => `<i>blah</i>` inside links... especially in the full `[foo](bar)` format which is our usual "if there's problems, do it this way" fallback. I'm not sure if escaping `_` as `\_` is the best option here, as it *feels* to me "broken" as-is, and if we fix it, your links will stop working. A better option might be to use `%5f` for `_`, i.e.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-%5f3D00%5f-BAML-not-IL.aspx

Comment: Just to prove that works in comments, either directly: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-%5f3D00%5f-BAML-not-IL.aspx or as a [formal link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-%5f3D00%5f-BAML-not-IL.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Marc, both solutions work.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that this is a bug, since it's inconsistent with the real in-post Markdown. Unfortunately given how the highly optimized comment MarkdownMini implementation works, it would require a huge change to make this behave as expected, and given the edge case-iness of this, I don't think this issue alone warrants the amount of work at the moment. So for the time being, I have to decline this.

As others have mentioned, the two ways to work around this are URL-encoding the underscore as `%5f`, or escaping it as `\_`. I have done the latter in your comment, so at least that link works now.

Comment: Thanks balpha, I agree with you; specially when a simple workaround is available these corner cases doesn't justify big changes.

Comment: This also breaks video rendering for in-post html. It took three of us several tries to get [this video](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/85829/revisions) to properly render, and the only way was to encode the underscores, which is crap because URLs aren't even supposed to use encoded stuff. Also italics aren't even parsed inside *words*...why are they parsed inside URLs? Also escaping the underscores works in preview but not rendered output, vice versa for encoding. So crazy all around.

Answer (score 3):

Underscores are Markdown syntax for italics. In comments, you have two options:

1. If you escape the underscores with backslashes, the URL will be treated correctly:

   ```
   http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-\_3D00\_-BAML-not-IL.aspx
   ```
2. If you use Markdown syntax for links, there **should** be no problem:

   ```
   [Compiled XAML = BAML not IL](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-_3D00_-BAML-not-IL.aspx)
   ```

   However, this does **not** work. It replaces the underscores with `<i>` and `</i>` tags.

   Right now, you have to use a workaround (like escaping the underscores).

Comment: Method 1: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-\_3D00\_-BAML-not-IL.aspx

Comment: Method 2: [Compiled XAML = BAML not IL](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2007/05/25/Compiled-XAML-_3D00_-BAML-not-IL.aspx)