# Links with double quotes or quotation marks don't work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links with quotation marks are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/links-with-quotation-marks-are-broken)

Hi, I tried posting this link

http://books.google.com/books?id=XWu70Oqz6RIC&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=wpf+"sharing+resources+between+assemblies"&source=bl&ots=FMQU9g3whX&sig=rhK8YR-OUddEKmSBMqZXv45gxNc&hl=en&ei=JlqpSqf5NNKBtge6jqXYBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#v=onepage&q=wpf%20%22sharing%20resources%20between%20assemblies%22&f=false

and the link text doesn't get highlighted (I think it's because it has a double quotes character in it). I also tried on with an apostrophe and it didn't work either, I had to resort to tinyurl in order to post both links.

Thanks.

P. S. As I posted the text I noticed another bug. The link text goes all the way to the right in my monitor (it goes beyond the text area and it even makes the browser screen horizontally scrollable!)

Comment: Can you post a link to the question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11943/the-markdown-editor-chokes-on-characters-in-urls/15580#15580

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel like I've [done this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/non-ascii-characters-in-external-links/21173#21173):

I intend to reuse [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/url-containing-closing-parentheses-are-trunked-in-comments-javadoc-idiom/13714#13714) over and over until this problem is fixed or the eventual heat death of the universe, whichever comes first.  Just mentally replace the parts about the parens with the specific character you are having problems with:

> I doubt we'll get this fixed, but you
>   can resolve it yourself by URL
>   encoding `(` and `)` as `%28` and
>   `%29`.  Since one of these bugs gets
>   posted every two to three days, here's
>   a simple rule of thumb:
>
> > Any characters in your URL other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `/.=?-+%&*`
> >     (and the `:` in "`http:`") should
> >     probably be URL encoded.
>
> I've cobbled together a quick page
>   that will encode the things that
>   shouldn't need encoding.  You can find
>   it [here](http://bstorer.com/so/encode.html).  It doesn't use any
>   jQuery, so it's probably completely
>   unreliable.  If you find anything it
>   should be encoding but isn't, let me
>   know.

Answer (score 1):

You have `"` quotation marks. You have to encode them. Replace the double-quote marks with this:

> %22

So that the part that looks like this:

> wpf+"sharing+resources+between+assemblies"&source=bl

is instead encoded as this:

> wpf+%22sharing+resources+between+assemblies%22&source=bl

One more thing. [`tinyurl` is never the answer](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001276.html).

Comment: with \"? What do you mean about tinyurl never being the answer?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001276.html