# Apostrophes in links don't get parsed correctly

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

For example:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life

Setting it up as a link through Markdown doesn't work either: [This is a link once it's posted, but not in the editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life). [The link works both during edit and after posting w/o apostrophe in the same URL, but it's obviously wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conways_Game_of_Life).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/some-links-dont-work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31165/adding-this-link-doesnt-work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/links-with-quotation-marks-are-broken http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11943/the-markdown-editor-chokes-on-characters-in-urls http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/url-containing-closing-parentheses-are-trunked-in-comments-javadoc-idiom

Comment: @Random Ha. That's what I get for trusting the "potentially duplicate posts" feature of the question posting UI. Thanks.

Comment: Amazingly, I don't think any of those are exact duplicates; there's three about `"`, one about `$`, and one about `)`

Comment: It should work with Markdown links now (in the editor as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can lead to some scripting exploits, we don't allow unencoded ' or " in URLs.

`<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life>`

Since Wikipedia supports workarounds for this and other problematic characters -- just omit them:

`<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conways_Game_of_Life>`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conways_Game_of_Life

or properly encode it

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Per the spec these chars are not allowed unencoded in URLs anyway

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2

```
  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

**Edit**: This works fine now with Markdown links, i.e. using `[bla](http://etc)`, the link button, Ctrl-L or similar.